# How to group multiple sets of duplicate integers in an array into their own array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, duplicates, lodash

I am trying to split an array of integers into an array of arrays by duplicate values. The original array is composed of a list of 6 digit integers, some of these integers come in pairs, others come in groups of 3 or 4s. I'd like to get these duplicates pushed to their own arrays and have all of these arrays of duplicates composed into an array of arrays that I can later loop through.

I've looked on in the lodash library for some method or combination of but can't quite find anything that seems to work. I've also tried a few different configurations with nested for loops but also am struggling with that.

```
const directory = "X/";
let files = fs.readdirSync(directory);
let first6Array = [ ];
for(i=0; i< files.length; i++){
 let first6 = files[i].substring(0, 6);
 first6Array.push(first6);
};
console.log(first6Array);
```

example output of first6Array:
[ '141848',
  '141848',
  '141848',
  '142851',
  '142851',
  '143275',
  '143275']

I'd like to end up with something like

let MasterArray = [[141848,141848,141848],[142851,142851],[143275,143275]];

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the same number occurs later; e.g. if `first6Array = ['1', '1', '2', '1']`, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: It shouldn't occur the dataset I'm drawing from should be sorted in ascending order  prior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `new Set()` to filter out the duplicates. 
Then you use the unique Array and filter for every value.

```js
const firstArray = [ '141848', '141848', '141848', '142851', '142851', '143275', '143275'];
const numberArray = firstArray.map(Number);
const masterArray = [];

const unique = new Set (numberArray); // Set {141848, 142851, 143275}
unique.forEach(u => {
  masterArray.push(numberArray.filter(e => e === u));
});

console.log(masterArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash, you can create a function with [flow](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow):

1. [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) the items by [truncating](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#truncate) them and converting to numbers.
2. [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) the value (the default).
3. convert to an array of arrays using [values](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#values).

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, map, truncate, groupBy, values } = _;

const truncate6 = s => truncate(s, { length: 6, omission: '' });

const fn = flow(
  pr(map, flow(truncate6, Number)),
  groupBy,
  values,
);

const firstArray = [ '141848abc', '141848efg', '141848hij', '142851klm', '142851opq', '143275rst', '143275uvw'];

const result = fn(firstArray);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` to create an object of arrays, indexed by number, and push to the associated array on each iteration (creating the array at the key first if needed), then get the values of the object:

```
const directory = "X/";
const files = fs.readdirSync(directory);
const output = Object.values(
  files.reduce((a, file) => {
    const num = Number(file.slice(0, 6));
    if (!a[num]) a[num] = [];
    a[num].push(num);
    return a;
  }, {})
);
```

It's pretty weird to have an array of identical values, though - you might consider a different data structure like

```
{
  '141848': 3,
  '142851': 2
}
```

to keep track of the number of occurrences of each number:

```
const output = files.reduce((a, file) => {
  const num = file.slice(0, 6);
  a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain exactly the result you desire, you need a nested `find`, something like this should works:

```
const directory = "X/";
let files = fs.readdirSync(directory);

let first6Array = files.reduce((acc, value)=> {
  let n = +value.substr(0, 6); // assumes it can't be NaN
  let arr = acc.find(nested => nested.find(item => item === n));

  if (arr) {
    arr.push(n);
  } else {
    acc.push([n]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(first6Array);
```

Notice that an hashmap instead, with the value and the number of occurrence, would be better, also in term of performance, but I don't think it mind since you have really few elements.

Also, it assumes the first six characters are actually numbers, otherwise the conversion would fail and you'll get `NaN`.

It would be safer adding a check to skip this scenario:

```
let n = +value.substr(0, 6);
if (isNaN(n)) {
  return acc;
}
// etc
```